# individual string length in array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, string-length

I need to create a function that takes in four strings and returns an array containing the length of each string. I was given this:

```
function stringLengths(str1, str2, str3, str4) {
  //
}
```

I've created an array of strings and I've searched google for so long all words are starting to look the same.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

here is your code

```
function stringLengths(str1, str2, str3, str4) { 
  return [str1.length, str2.length, str3.length, str4.length]
}

console.log(stringLengths('1','bb','ccc','dddd'))
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Rest Paremeters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) to convert arguments in to array and then `map` them to get your required result. Below is my snippet.

```js
function stringLengths(...strings){
  return strings.map(string => string.length);
}
console.log(stringLengths("","something","something else"))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use rest syntax and `.map()` function to get an array of string's length:

```js
const stringLengths = (...str) => str.map(({ length }) => length);

console.log(stringLengths('lorem', 'ipsum'));
console.log(stringLengths('lorem', 'ipsum', 'sit', 'amet'));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change your function definition, you can also use the [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) object.

```js
function stringLengths(str1, str2, str3, str4)
{    
    return [...arguments].map(x => x.length);
}

console.log(stringLengths("hello", "cruel", "world", "of", "darkness"));
```

Or like this:

```js
function stringLengths(str1, str2, str3, str4)
{    
    return Object.values(arguments).map(x => x.length);
}

console.log(stringLengths("hello", "cruel", "world", "of", "darkness"));
```

Comment: I personally don't see much point in keeping the function signature unchanged if you're using `arguments` under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

There are excellent answers already to make `stringLengths` work with any number of parameters. However, all (so far) assume that each parameter is a string.

Which can lead to unexpected results:

- Both arrays and functions have a `length` property
- Any objects can be crafted with a `length` property

Or even errors:

- Things like `null` or `undefined` will throw an error when attempting to read properties from them.

```js
const stringLengths = (...strs) =>
  strs.map(s => s.length);

console.log(
  stringLengths(1, 2)
);

console.log(
  stringLengths({length: ''}, [''], (a, b) => '')
);

console.log(
  stringLengths(null, null)
);
```

You can write a decorator `filterStrings` which you can apply to `stringLengths` so that it gets only strings:

```js
const stringLengths = (...strs) =>
  strs.map(s => s.length);

const filterStrings = fn => (...args) =>
  fn(...args.filter(arg => typeof arg === 'string'));
  
const safeStringLengths = filterStrings(stringLengths);

console.log(
  safeStringLengths(1, 2)
);

console.log(
  safeStringLengths({length: ''}, [''], (a, b) => '')
);

console.log(
  safeStringLengths(null, null)
);

console.log(
  safeStringLengths("foo", "bar", "foobar")
);
```

`filterStrings` is the function that actually gets all the parameters, it keeps only strings and pass them on to `stringLengths`.

*Why do it this way?*

It depends on your context really. The nice thing about the decorator is that it allows you to move the validation of the parameters outside of `stringLengths` and let the function do just one thing.

In some scenarios you can simply trust your parameters and having validation in your function would be useless. In other scenarios, you can't. Being able to combine functions allows you to keep things separated and organised.